# docker-compose.yml invalid: app.build contains an invalid type, it should be a string

Tags: string, docker, docker-compose

Running `$ docker-compose up` when I have my `docker-compose.yml` as the following, everything works as expected:

```
app:
  build: .
```

However when I have `docker-compose.yml` as (which appears to valid within the [docker-compose reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build)):

```
app:
  build:
    context: .
```

I get the following **error:**

```
$ docker-compose up
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
app.build contains an invalid type, it should be a string
```

I've also tried `context: "."` with no joy. Please help! Many thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The format you're using is for [Version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#version-2). You're currently using [Version 1](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#version-1) format.

For Version 1, Docker Compose expects a string:

```
app:
  build: .
```

For Version 2, Docker Compose [expects a string or object](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build), but you must specify that your Docker Compose file is Version 2:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I accidentally used dashes before my build entries (**incorrect**):

```
  build:
      - context: ../crafter
      - dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

However, **correct** would be (without the dashes):

```
  build:
      context: ../crafter
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```